# Can't get usb ethernet adapter running under CentOS 6 minimal

Tags: centos, drivers, usb-drive, dmesg

I have a cheap usb adapter and using it on a minmal CentOS 6.7 box, when I plug in the adapter it's recognized as usb device but not as ethernet adapter, although I've loaded these kernel modules:

```
dm9601                  7261  0 
usbnet                 38366  1 dm9601
mii                     5376  3 dm9601,usbnet,r8169
```

and this what I get from `dmesg`:

```
usb 2-1.2: new full speed USB device number 3 using ehci_hcd
usb 2-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=0fe6, idProduct=9700
usb 2-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
usb 2-1.2: Product: USB 2.0 10/100M Ethernet Adaptor
usb 2-1.2: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
```

on the other hand, it works immediately after being plugged into an Ubuntu machine, with this output from `dmesg`:

```
[ 1398.631380] usb 6-1: new full-speed USB device number 3 using ohci-pci
[ 1398.796441] usb 6-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0fe6, idProduct=9700
[ 1398.796453] usb 6-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 1398.796461] usb 6-1: Product: USB 2.0 10/100M Ethernet Adaptor
[ 1398.864982] dm9601 6-1:1.0 eth1: register 'dm9601' at usb-0000:00:13.1-1, Davicom DM96xx USB 10/100 Ethernet, 00:e0:4c:53:44:58
[ 1398.886090] dm9601 6-1:1.0 enx00e04c534458: renamed from eth1
[ 1398.913870] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enx00e04c534458: link is not ready
[ 1398.992407] dm9601 6-1:1.0 enx00e04c534458: link up, 100Mbps, full-duplex, lpa 0xFFFF
```

How can I trigger module `dm9601` to recognize the device ?

**EDIT:** output of `modinfo dm9601` on CentOS

```
filename:       /lib/modules/2.6.32-504.el6.x86_64/kernel/drivers/net/usb/dm9601.ko
license:        GPL
description:    Davicom DM9601 USB 1.1 ethernet devices
author:         Peter Korsgaard <jacmet@sunsite.dk>
srcversion:     4F5EB9E08E2E987CF777DB0
alias:          usb:v0A46p9000d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v0FE6p8101d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v0A47p9601d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v0A46p8515d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v0A46p0268d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v0A46p6688d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v0A46p9601d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v07AAp9601d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
depends:        mii,usbnet
vermagic:       2.6.32-504.el6.x86_64 SMP mod_unload modversions
```

on Ubuntu:

```
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-21-generic/kernel/drivers/net/usb/dm9601.ko
license:        GPL
description:    Davicom DM96xx USB 10/100 ethernet devices
author:         Peter Korsgaard <jacmet@sunsite.dk>
srcversion:     9188BA9738A6BCF0D399BC5
alias:          usb:v0A46p1269d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0A46p0269d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0A46p9622d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0A46p9621d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0A46p9620d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0A46p9000d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0FE6p9700d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0FE6p8101d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0A47p9601d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0A46p8515d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0A46p0268d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0A46p6688d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0A46p9601d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v07AAp9601d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
depends:        usbnet,mii
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-21-generic SMP mod_unload modversions
```

Comment: post output of `modinfo dm9601`